# I cannot locate production log files on Elastic Beanstalk ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Rails app to Elastic Beanstalk.  I am trying to locate the production log files from the previous day.  They are not present in the zipped bundle which can be downloaded from the AWS EB console.  They are not present in the /var/log directory of the ec2 instance.  in /var/app/support/logs there are only todays log files.

Is there anywhere else to look?

Is my EB environment configured incorrectly?  If so, how do I correct the problem?

Thanks in advance for any hints or tips.

Comment: Have you turned automatic log rotation feature enabled? If you have, they are written to S3 bucket. There should be a bucket elasticbeanstalk-<region>-<account ID> in your S3. Under that, go to resources/environments/logs/<Instance ID>.

Comment: @RakeshBollampally,  Thanks for the suggestion.  Automatic rotation is not enabled and no logs are present at the location you mentioned.

Comment: Can you check when the instance was launched? May be yesterdays instance was terminated due to some failure and a new instance was launched? In this case, I don't think you will be able to get the logs as Beanstalk storage is not persistent. Also, try getting logs from EB console

Comment: The instance was launched 3 days prior to me creating this post.  I have enabled log rotation, however, since your initial comment and the logs are now available on s3.  So I have at least sidestepped the issue, thanks to your input.  Thank you @RakeshBollampally.

Answer (score 11):

All your system logs should be in `/var/log` you'll probably see `.log.1` at the end of the log files, this is because they are rotated.

For your application, I'd look in: `/var/app/support/logs`, here you'll find logs for Passenger (if that's what your stack runs). You'll probably see something like this in that directory:

```
access.log
development.log
healthd/
passenger.log
production.log
rotated/
```

**If you are using the NGINX and Puma stack** (or other newly updated 2018 eb stacks), your appwill be running at: `/var/app/current`

Comment: In my case I just went to `/var/app/current` and then did `tail -f log/production.log`.

Comment: Yes, but how to have this production.log streamed to CloudWatch Log Groups? I see there all the other logs, except for production.log - although I have the Log streaming/retention enabled.

Comment: @Maris Were you able to export production.log to CloudWatch Log Groups?