# Where do I find the error log of a Rails app on the production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app is working fine on a local server. After deploying it on production (AWS EC2), I see this "classic" Rails error page:
[image]

I thought that the errors are logged to the file `current/log/production.log`, but when I looked in it, there's no error captured. I can only see there the following:

```
I, [2019-06-09T12:12:04.353438 #12855]  INFO -- : Started GET "/constact-us" for 185.44.76.84 at 2019-06-09 12:12:04 +0000
I, [2019-06-09T12:12:04.355034 #12855]  INFO -- : Processing by MyAppSite::SiteController#contact_us as HTML
```

There's logged accessing the URL, but not the error message. Where do I find it? I added some pure HTML/image to that template, so I think the error must be related to some issue with assets (and precompilation).

However, where do I find the full error message?

I am looking to the `config/environments/production.rb` file and regarding logs, there's "only" this line:

```
config.log_level = :info
```

Any advise how to figure out the error message?

**EDIT:** I just realized that I also have integrated Rollbar to the app and it hasn't caught the error either.

**EDIT 2:** error from the nginx log:

```
2019/06/09 13:47:14 [error] 987#0: *7824941 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: IP, server: www.my_website.com, request: "GET /contact-us HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp_production.sock:/contact-us", host: "www.my_website.com
```

Thank you

Comment: What web server do you use? How did you install that server?

Comment: It's probably in the logs for either nginx or apache, do you have access to them on AWS?

Comment: @spickermann I use `nginx`, I installed it as an image.

Comment: @Eyeslandic when I look to the file `/var/log/nginx/myapp_production.error.log`, there's this "error" message: `2019/06/09 13:47:14 [error] 987#0: *7824941 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: IP, server: www.my_website.com, request: "GET /contact-us HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp_production.sock:/contact-us", host: "www.my_website.com"` -- but it doesn't really say what's wrong there

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277164/i-cannot-locate-production-log-files-on-elastic-beanstalk-ec2-instance helps?